# Driver [app.database] not supported. Laravel 5.1

Tags: laravel

**Driver [app.database] not supported. Laravel 5.1**

I have cloned a repository of a project of the company, and when trying to lift the project I throw myself the following error, already reviewed the connection parameters and all this well,

The error is with W7 and Laravel 5.1.

config.databases.php
return [

'fetch' => PDO::FETCH_CLASS,

'default' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),

'connections' => [

```
'sqlite' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlite',
    'database' => storage_path('database.sqlite'),
    'prefix'   => '',
],

'mysql' => [
    'driver'    => 'mysql',
    'host'      => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'port'      => '4242',
    'database'  => env('DB_DATABASE', '***'),
    'username'  => env('DB_USERNAME', '***'),
    'password'  => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'   => 'utf8',
    'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
    'prefix'    => '',
    'strict'    => false,
    'options'   => [
    \PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => true
    ]
],

'pgsql' => [
    'driver'   => 'pgsql',
    'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
    'schema'   => 'public',
],

'sqlsrv' => [
    'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
    'host'     => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
    'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
    'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
    'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
    'charset'  => 'utf8',
    'prefix'   => '',
],
```

],

'migrations' => 'migrations',

'redis' => [

```
'cluster' => false,

'default' => [
    'host'     => '127.0.0.1',
    'port'     => 6379,
    'database' => 0,
],
```

],
];

Comment: Please show us your `config/database.php` settings. (Censoring any hostnames or passwords that may be in there, please.)

Comment: What's the value of `DB_CONNECTION` in your `.env` file?

Comment: DB_CONNECTION=mysql

Comment: Do you have mysql PHP module installed?

Comment: yes, I have laravel 5.6 projects running on my localhost, I do not understand why I give databases error with laravel 5.1